# Creating a shared folder with special characters

Tags: c#, windows, cmd, localhost, shared-directory

I am writing a test that creates folders and shares on my machine in order to test a service.
Now i am able to create all special characters named folders but when trying to run the command "net share {name}={path}" i get an error that the file is not found.  Same with Powershell script.

When i manually click on the folder and share it, it works.
Here is some of the names i am having trouble with, i hope someone is able to help me with this. Thanks.

====☠====
þpq®§štúûµvwxýÿzž...
—¤÷(`[¤¤]´)÷¤—

Comment: `net share {name}="{path}"` ? notice the `""` around `{path}`

Comment: Are you running powershell as Administrator?

Comment: the actual command is $@"net share ""{name}""=""{path}""". it has to be this way in order to account for spaces in the name

Comment: yes indeed i am running as administrator.

Comment: Try using `$@"net share {name}=""{path}"""` there is `""` in excess in before name

Comment: Nope, the issue is not with the command. if you create a folder say with the name —¤÷(`[¤¤]´)÷¤— you'll get the error

Comment: See `chcp /?`. 65001 is UTF8. You will also have to choose a font in Console Properties that has those characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up ignoring those characters.
After further investigation, i found out that regardless or not windows being able to create folders with these names, creating a share have more restrictions besides **"/ \ : * ? " < > | "** .
Also if a character is non UTF-8, and it sort of "disappears" after naming a folder, it will also not be able to share it.

Hope this helps.